# Sql ChangeTracking clean up tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When using Sql 2008 Change Tracking is there a way to manually clean up the tracking tables?

I know about the CHANGE_RETENTION and AUTO_CLEANUP properties but would perfer more control over the cleanup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically these Change Tracking information are stored in Internal Tables and no option to clean up manually. But still we can clear by disabling/enabling change tracking for a tables.

```
alter table <tableName> disable change_tracking  
alter table <tableName> enable change_tracking
```

THis command will clean up all change tracking related to specific table.

Comment: In the context of MS Sync with Sql CT this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable change tacking for all tables:

```sql
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING"
   , @whereand=" and exists (
   select null
   from sys.change_tracking_tables ctt
   where ctt.object_id = o.id
)
"
```